# Error in printing data.frame in excel using XLSX package in R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

The dataframe is visible with out any error. But when the same is printed using write.xlsx fucnction of the package XLSX, it gives the error.

```
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([D)V not found.
```

The dput of the data.frame looks like:

```
Timestamp         qs          pqs        logqs         es         p_imp      dep    r_dep       agg_rtn
               (time)      (dbl)        (dbl)        (dbl)      (dbl)         (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)         (dbl)
1 2015-05-04 09:29:59 0.05788732 0.0007478696 0.0007478545 0.09633803 -0.0446830986 3533.518 274079.9 -0.0006432937
2 2015-05-04 10:00:00 0.04948394 0.0006362707 0.0006362707 0.07586009  0.0088016055 2416.431 187953.1  0.0000000000
3 2015-05-04 10:30:00 0.05554795 0.0007142532 0.0007142532 0.06417808 -0.0002739726 3245.574 252422.0  0.0000000000
4 2015-05-04 10:59:59 0.04863014 0.0006194244 0.0006194244 0.08434442  0.0024951076 3563.401 279503.9  0.0000000000
5 2015-05-04 11:30:00 0.05761986 0.0007319037 0.0007319037 0.07851027  0.0154965753 2010.943 158429.1 -0.0006339144
6 2015-05-04 12:00:00 0.04957627 0.0006285051 0.0006285051 0.07025424  0.0070762712 1819.908 143546.0  0.0000000000
Variables not shown: vol_30_sum (dbl), vol_30_mean (dbl), p_return_sqr (dbl), p_return_mean (dbl), Lim_or_out (dbl),
  closing_price (dbl), closing_vol (dbl)
```

Kindly help in resolving this error.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the same is printed using write.xlsx function"? Are you doing `print(write.xlsx(...))`? Or is the error just when you call `write.xlsx(...)`? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Output is printed using: write.xlsx(q1, file = paste0(File Address","_6",".xlsx"),sheetName="Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Also, your "dput of the data.frame" does not look like something that `dput(my.dataframe)` would produce, can you look at `class(my.dataframe)` and confirm that the (only) class is "data.frame"?

Comment: class(q1)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Still no reproducible example, but from your `class(q1)` it appears that `q1` is a `tbl_df` (the sort of dataframe that the `dplyr` package produces) whereas `write.xlsx` expects a `data.frame`.

Try giving `write.xlsx` a plain `data.frame` as it expects. e.g.

```
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(q1), ...)
```

Here's a **[reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)** (i.e. you could copy-paste it into your R session to reproduce the bug + fix).

```
library(dplyr)
iris2 <- tbl_df(iris)
class(iris2) # like yours
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame" 

# Now let's try to write to XLSX using command as mentioned in your comments
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(iris2, file='test.xlsx', sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
# Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
#   method setCellValue with signature ([D)V not found
# In addition: Warning message:
# In if (is.na(value)) { :
#  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
# ^--- we can reproduce your error. This is the point of a reproducible example, so we can see if our fixes work for you.
```

Now let's try fix it by making sure that write.xlsx gets a data.frame, not a tbl_df!

```
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(iris2), file='test.xlsx', sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
# huzzah!
```

Comment: Just adding as.data.frame() is the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 11):

I find this happens when grouping variables with dplyr.  If you end a chain with %>% ungroup () it appears to resolve

Comment: This worked! Ending with ungroup() allowed me to keep my dplyr chain of analysis in tact and still export with write.xlsx()

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a bug with the Date/Time format of the first column (Timestamp). If you convert the first column to character, it should work. 
So, you may change your first column to

```
q1[,1] <- as.character(q1[,1])
```

and try again...