# Can't export a data frame to xlsx file

Tags: r

I need to export  a data frame to xlsx file

```
DATA_BASE<-as.data.frame(DATA_BASE)

# EXPORT THE DATATABLE TO CSV FILE IN EXCEL

library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(DATA_BASE),"C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/NEW_NEW_NEW/DATA_VISUALIZATION.xlsx",sheetName="Sheet1")
```

, But I get this error :

> Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook") :
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I searched and I get a response here :

[Error in printing data.frame in excel using XLSX package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428041/error-in-printing-data-frame-in-excel-using-xlsx-package-in-r)

But I already convert the **DATA_BASE** as data frame!

How do I resolve this, please?

Comment: try using package `openxlsx`

Comment: @phiver, thank you for your response, But I get an error in installing this package! `Error in library(openxlsx) :no package named 'openxlsx' is found`

Comment: try installing it first. `install.packages("openxlsx")`

Comment: @phiver, yes I did this and also I changed each timethe CRAN and I also tried this `install.packages("openxlsx",dependicies=TRUE)`.

Comment: If you are trying to create a CSV anyway, `write.csv` or `write.table( .. , sep = ",")` would be an option.

Comment: @r.user.05apr look what I get `unused argument (sep = ",")`

Comment: `write.table(DATA_BASE, file = "c: ..\\xx.csv", sep = ","); write.csv(DATA_BASE, file = "c: ..\\xx.csv")`. If you are using write.csv, you don't need sep. Hope that's the problem.

Comment: @r.user.05apr, thank you very much ! it works

Comment: if you want to stick with the xlsx package you have to increase the memory with a command something like this `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")` - restart your session, run this command then the `write.xlsx` command

Comment: @Mike, thank you for this information.